# VScode shortcut for switch to last tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I saw other question, but it was seven years ago, so maybe is now possible to make shortcut what will switch us to last tab? I mean like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> in Google browser.

Comment: `Ctrl+9` goes to the last tab in each group in vscode too. Or `Alt+0`.

Comment: Hmmm can I ask you for your config because it's not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did it by installing extension what allow me make shortcut for multiple command and assign `ctrl+0` to go to first tab and then go one tab before.

To do that, install extension `CTRL+P` and type `ext install ryuta46.multi-command` after that add this to shortcut JSON file

```
    {
    "key": "ctrl+0",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1",
            "workbench.action.previousEditor"
        ]
    }
    },
```